# PHP class for file handling and creation

Tags: php, object-oriented, file, file-system

This is a very simple class to handle files.

It allows to access, create and modify files in the system or 2 fake files (one in memory and other similar to `/dev/null` or `nul`).

Windows has a 'feature' that automatically converts all the line endings to the correct one. That is one of the features included.

The fake `/dev/null` is simply a file that works similarly to the 'real deal'.

All reads to it succeed, all writes success, using `seek` on it succeeds but its size is always 0.

```
<?

    namespace IO;

    final class InvalidFilename extends \Exception {
        function __construct( $filename ){
            $this->message = 'Invalid filename: "' . $filename . '"';
        }
    }
    final class InvalidMode extends \Exception {
        function __construct( $mode ){
            $this->message = 'Invalid mode: "' . $mode . '"';
        }
    }
    final class WriteError extends \Exception {
        function __construct( $filename ){
            $this->message = 'Could not write into "' . $filename . '"';
        }
    }
    final class ReadError extends \Exception {
        function __construct( $filename ){
            $this->message = 'Could not read from "' . $filename . '"';
        }
    }
    final class EOF extends \Exception {
        function __construct( $filename ){
            $this->message = 'End Of File "' . $filename . '"';
        }
    }

    final class File {

        const READ = 1;
        const WRITE = 2;
        const BINARY = 4;
        const MEMORY = "\1";
        const VOID = "\0";

        const EOL = PHP_EOL;
        const EOL_WIN = "\r\n";
        const EOL_LINUX = "\n";
        const EOL_OLD_MAC = "\r";

        private $info=array(
            'content'=>'',
            'path'=>'',
            'name'=>'',
            'length'=>0,
            'p'=>0,
            'mode'=>1
        );

        function __construct( $filename, $mode = 1 ){

            $this->info['mode'] = $mode & 7;
            if( !$this->info['mode'] )
            {
                throw new InvalidMode( $mode );
            }

            if( $filename != self::MEMORY && $filename != self::VOID )
            {

                $this->info['path'] = dirname( $filename );
                if( !$this->info['path'] )
                {
                    $this->info['path'] = getcwd();
                }

                $this->info['name'] = basename( $filename );
                if( !$this->info['path'] )
                {
                    throw new InvalidFilename( $filename );
                }

                if( $mode & self::READ )
                {
                    $this->info['content'] = file_get_contents( $filename );

                    if( $this->info['content'] === false)
                    {
                        throw new ReadError( $filename );
                    }

                    if( !( $mode & self::BINARY ) )
                    {
                        $this->fix_eol();
                    }

                    $this->info['length'] = strlen( $this->info['content'] );
                }

            }
            else
            {
                $this->info['path'] = $this->info['name'] = $filename;
            }
        }

        function fix_eol()
        {
            $this->info['content'] = str_replace( array( self::EOL_WIN, self::EOL_LINUX, self::EOL_OLD_MAC ), self::EOL, $this->info['content'] );
        }

        function eof()
        {
            switch( $this->info['name'] )
            {
                case self::VOID:
                    return false;
                default:
                    return $this->info['p'] >= $this->info['length'];
            }
        }

        function read( $bytes = -1 )
        {
            if( $this->info['name'] == self::VOID )
            {
                return '';
            }

            if( $this->info['name'] != self::MEMORY && !( $this->info['mode'] & self::READ ) )
            {
                throw new ReadError( $this->info['name'] );
            }

            if( $this->eof() )
            {
                throw new EOF( $this->info['name'] );
            }

            if( $bytes < 0 || $bytes > $this->info['length'] - $this->info['p'] )
            {
                $bytes = $this->info['length'] - $this->info['p'];
            }

            $p = $this->info['p'];
            $this->info['p'] += $bytes;

            return '' . substr( $this->info['content'], $p, $bytes );
        }
        function readln( $trim = true )
        {
            if( $this->info['name'] == self::VOID )
            {
                return '';
            }

            if( $this->info['name'] != self::MEMORY && !( $this->info['mode'] & self::READ ) )
            {
                throw new ReadError( $this->info['name'] );
            }

            if( $this->eof() )
            {
                throw new EOF( $this->info['name'] );
            }

            $line_end = strpos( $this->info['content'], self::EOL, $this->info['p'] );
            $p = $this->info['p'];

            if( $line_end === false )
            {
                $this->info['p'] = $this->info['length'];
                return '' . substr( $this->info['content'], $p );
            }
            else
            {
                $this->info['p'] = $line_end + strlen( self::EOL );
                return '' . substr( $this->info['content'], $p, $trim ? $line_end : $this->info['p'] );
            }
        }
        function read_bytes( $bytes )
        {
            $data = $this->read( $bytes );
            $return = array();

            for( $i = 0, $l = strlen( $data ); $i < $l; $i++ )
            {
                $return[] = ord( $data[$i] );
            }

            return $return;
        }

        function write( $data )
        {
            if( $this->info['name'] != self::VOID )
            {
                if( $this->info['name'] != self::MEMORY && !( $this->info['mode'] & self::WRITE ) )
                {
                    throw new WriteError( $this->info['name'] );
                }

                list($begin,$end) = array( substr( $this->info['content'],0, $this->info['p'] ), substr( $this->info['content'], $this->info['p'] ) );

                $this->info['p'] = strlen( $begin . $data );

                $this->info['content'] = $begin . $data . $end;

                if( !( $this->info['mode'] & self::BINARY ) )
                {
                    $this->fix_eol();
                }

                $this->info['length'] = strlen( $this->info['content'] );
            }

            return $this;
        }
        function writeln( $data )
        {
            return $this->write( $data . self::EOL );
        }
        function write_bytes()
        {
            $data = '';
            foreach( func_get_args() as $byte )
            {
                $data .= chr( $byte );
            }
            return $this->write( $data );
        }

        function seek( $byte )
        {
            if( $this->info['name'] != self::VOID && is_numeric( $byte ) )
            {
                if( $byte >= $this->info['length'] )
                {
                    $this->info['p'] = $this->info['length'];
                }
                else if( $byte >= 0)
                {
                    $this->info['p'] = (int)$byte;
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->info['p'] = $this->info['length'] - 1;
                }
            }

            return $this;
        }
        function start()
        {
            return $this->seek( 0 );
        }
        function end()
        {
            return $this->seek( -1 );
        }

        function pos()
        {
            return $this->info['p'];
        }

        function size()
        {
            return $this->info['length'];
        }

        function save( $return = false )
        {
            if( $this->info['name'] == self::VOID || $this->info['name'] == self::MEMORY )
            {
                return !!$return;
            }
            else
            {
                return file_put_contents( $this->info['path'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $this->info['name'], $this->info['content'] );
            }
        }

        function destroy()
        {
            $this->info = array(
                'content'=>'',
                'path'=>'',
                'name'=>'',
                'length'=>0,
                'p'=>0,
                'mode'=>1
            );
        }
    }
```

It is quite lengthy.

Here's an example of usage:

```
$file = new IO\File(File::MEMORY);

//Should output 12345
echo $file->writeln(123)->start()->writeln(12345)->start()->readln(true);
```

In terms of usability and readability, what else should I change?

Notice the lack of atomic changes and blocking. That wasn't the aim. The aim was to get the content, change it and then save it to the file (if it is a 'real' file).

Comment: @Quill Sorry, I've only noticed that now. I usually start function with the curly bracket on the same line, but on loops it is in a new line. Probably a bad habit I got from my boss when writting CSS. But I've noticed that it isn't following always that style.

Comment: Why do you have an info array with six keys instead of six private variables?

Comment: @bdsl I have no idea at this point. Both work properly,  but maybe separate variables would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Each class belongs in an own file**

It seems to be overhead but remember: Each class has one task to solve and the same goes for files. In small projects it does not matter that much but as soon as a project grows it helps a lot. My namespaces are similiar to the path of the class location. As of this I know where every class is located - everytime I instantiate a class.

**Namespaces**

If you have not read yourself into namespaces I recommend it. Namespaces combined with an autoloader are a great way to make your daily developer life a lot easier. When using an autoloader you have another reason for having one class in one file.

**further aspects**

- In function save of class File you wrote `return !!$return` I guess there's one ! too much.

Comment: Well, I agree about the namespaces, but a class per file isn't it too much? And woouldn't the code be worst since I have to look around where I'm declaring the exception? And on the `save` method, I think it should be actually `return true;`. I don't remember... (Add there: comment the code!). About the namespace, I **totally** agree! And that would be the best option. Thank you for the idea!

Comment: "If you have not read yourself into namespaces I recommend it." --> 2nd line... Autoloaders are a bad idea since they make the code even harder to read and debug. When you get the WSOD (White Screen Of Death), you won't know which one of the 6 files is failing.

Comment: Oh my bad. Well, if I experience a blank page I will take a look into the error log of the php application. In case it's empty or does not help I take a look in the error log of the apache server. Edit: An application should make usage of log files.

Comment: Yes, it should, but in a production server you don't want those since a small mistake (using `$array` when undeclared or `$array[a]` instead of `$array['a']`) or by mistake leaving `error_reporting(0)` behind or even having the error log disabled on the `php.ini` loaded by php without you knowing or any other reason might cause the white page without an error log.

Comment: You're right this should not happen but it's not recommend to develop on a production server anyway. Well, ifI have to I will enable error reporting only for my ip before making further steps.  So even if I forget to remove it users will not see any errors but the blank page.

Comment: Sometimes you don't have a choice. And sometimes you have to debug someone else's code. Just imagine the nightmare that would be if he had 7 files, 6 autoload from somewhere. And then you have another class that also has an autoloader. Just imagine the clash that would be on your server, and the rain of fatal errors.

Comment: This is a hell, indeed but this does not mean you can't make your life easier. Just because others don't structure their code good does not mean you can't do that.

Comment: I recommend that you say the hell away from autoloaders. I'm not saying it doesn't make it easy for you to write 1 library. But it is a nightmare when you combine more than one together.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel namespaces _are not_ a bad idea. If you get a WSOD then check the logs  in your web server, apache or nginx, it shouldn't be an issue. If this is a CLI script, then use monologger to log exception messages to a file. In all this time, I've *never* had a problem with autoloaders and errors in production servers.

Comment: @AlanChavez I have nothing against namespaces: I actually like them! I don't like autoloaders. Those are evil to me!

Comment: Hopefully your mind has changed by now - auto loading is the right way to go. And using a framework is the best way to go - it deals with all these issues you've mentioned. Not using auto loading makes handling dependencies painful for any non-trivial project.